# How to use check library with CTest for unit testing in C

Tags: c, cmake, ctest, check-framework

I have project in which I want to use [check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) library for unit testing.

My current project is using CMake and has following structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── COPYING
├── ChangeLog
├── README
├── src
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── main.c
│   ├── core-test
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── main.c
│   └── scrypt
└── doc
    └── protocol.txt
```

In `core-test` I have unit tests for `core` module. In `scrypt-test` I will have tests for `scrypt` module and so on.

---

Does using `check` with CTest make sense?

If yes: how do I connect unit test that use `check` to CMake/CTest project? Do I need additional configuration for CTest to interpret results from `check`-enabled executables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `check` with CTest is possible, unfortunately not convenient.

When unit tests using `check` fail they will be counted as a failure in CTest. The problem is, that CTest doesn't show output of application that failed<sup>1</sup>. The other downside is that CTest doesn't count individual `check` tests, so a "single" failed test could mean multiple `check` tests. I wasn't able to find a way to make CTest interpret check results.

---

1. You can force printing of output by creating `CTestCustom.cmake` file in *build* directory (the same one in which you run `make` or `ctest`) with following contents:

   set (CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST "cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log")